# AWS ec2 import-instance error-No valid partitions. Not a valid volume.[Client error]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-server, ec2-api-tools, vmdk

I am trying to import a SO VMDK file(OVA/OVF) of Ubuntu server 14.04 to AWS ,But facing the below error

[image],

even though the machine seems to have proper partitioning and volumes

[image].

This happens only in case of Ubuntu server, while Windows server machines are successfully imported.I am trying to import using the ec2-api-tools only.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with OVA images exported from VirtualBox. In my case converting it to **raw image** format worked. So if you  are using VirtualBox, import the OVA to it, and then convert `VDI` storage drive to `raw`. For example:

```
VBoxManage clonehd "/mnt/b/VirtualBox VMs/ub.vdi" ./ub.img --format raw
```

Then you upload `ub.img` to S3, and use that in your  `containers.json` file for `aws ec2 import-image` command. For example:

```
[
  {
    "Description": "My Server OVA",
    "Format": "raw",
    "Url": "s3://<your-s3-bucket>/ub.img"
  }
]
```

The command:

```
aws ec2 import-image --description "My server VM" --disk-containers "file:///./containers.json"
```

and to monitor the import process:

```
aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks --import-task-ids <import-id-from-previous-command>
```