# AWS EC2 Export Task Fails with "ClientError: No valid partitions. Not a valid volume."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to export EC2 as a image to S3. On trying the command below, the job gets submitted.

```
aws ec2 create-instance-export-task --export-to-s3-task file://E:\ec2-export.json --instance-id i-0d687664c1bf1221a --target-environment vmware
```

However, after a few minutes, it gets cancelled with error

> ClientError: No valid partitions. Not a valid volume.

I tried a few combinations of target environments (such as vmware, Microsoft) and image types such as ova, vmd, vmdk but get this error everytime.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736254/aws-ec2-import-instance-error-no-valid-partitions-not-a-valid-volume-client-er) question but it didn't help.

Any points will be highly appreciated. Thank you.